# Twitter API: when and how long is media_id safe to use after media upload?

Tags: sttwitterapi

In order to save bandwidth, I try to reuse the media_id that the twitter API returns for multiple tweets, preferably indefinitely. This works, after an upload I can use the same id multiple times, but as soon as when I for example delete a tweet that uses that specific media_id, the id seems to be invalidated and the API returns a

`[324] Invalid media status`

This made me go on a search for how long and when these media ids are actually usable. I found nothing. Is there anyone with some experience in this field?